# Vagrant takes a long time to mount default shared folder

Tags: linux, vagrant, bitlocker

vagrant 1.9

virtualbox 5.1.12

base box:  https://github.com/CommanderK5/packer-centos-template/releases/download/0.7.2/vagrant-centos-7.2.box

Current Laptop: Windows7 on Dell Latitude E7270 with 250gb ssd on bitlocker.

So with that out of the way, I was previously using vagrant with the same version of vagrant, virtualbox and base box on a different computer with a mechanical hdd without bitlocker.  Everything is ok until I upgraded my laptop.

In vagrant if we do `vagrant init` in a folder and launch vagrant it will mount the folder with the VagrantFile to the /vagrant on the guest machine.  On the current laptop it takes a loong time for vagrant to mount this shared folder.

Do you think its bitlocket that might be causing this issue?

Thanks